# I'm trying to have my game automatically place something in a cell, but I'm not sure how to get the cell (js)

Tags: javascript, bots, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to make a tic-tac-toe game in HTML, with a bot that plays as the circle. However, I am not sure how to get the bot to place a circle into a random cell. Everything else is completely working, I am just having problems with the bot (marked in the js code). What I have tried is using Math.random to get a random cell, however I have not figured out how to get a cell from that. I believe that might be the answer, but I am just stuck. Any help would be awesome!

The code below has been shortened to the parts that may be important

HTML:

```html
<body>
    <div class="board" id="board">
    <div class="cell" datacell></div>
    <div class="cell" datacell></div>
    <div class="cell" datacell></div>
    <div class="cell" datacell></div>
    <div class="cell" datacell></div>
    <div class="cell" datacell></div>
    <div class="cell" datacell></div>
    <div class="cell" datacell></div>
    <div class="cell" datacell></div>
</div>
<div class="winning-message" id="winningMessage">
    <div data-winning-message-text></div>
    <button id = "restartButton">Restart?</button>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
.board {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
}

.cell {
    width: var(--cell-size);
    height: var(--cell-size);
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cell.x,
.cell.circle {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.cell.x::before,
.cell.x::after,
.cell.circle::before {
    background-color: black;
}

.board.x .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::before,
.board.x .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::after,
.board.circle .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::before{
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.cell.x::before,
.cell.x::after,
.board.x .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::before,
.board.x .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(var(--mark-size) * .15);
    height: var(--mark-size);
}

.cell.x::before,
.board.x .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.cell.x::after,
.board.x .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.cell.circle::before,
.cell.circle::after,
.board.circle .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::before,
.board.circle .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
border-radius: 50%;

}

.cell.circle::before,
.board.circle .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::before{
    width: var(--mark-size);
    height: var(--mark-size);
}

.cell.circle::after,
.board.circle .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::after {
    width: calc(var(--mark-size) * .7);
    height: calc(var(--mark-size) * .7);
    background-color: white;
}
```

JS (has the issue):

```js
const X_CLASS = 'x'
const CIRCLE_CLASS = 'circle'
const WINNING_COMBINATIONS = [ [0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], [0,4,8] , [2,4,6] ]
const cellElements = document.querySelectorAll('.cell')
const board = document.getElementById('board')
const winningMessageElement = document.getElementById('winningMessage')
const restartButton = document.getElementById('restartButton')
const winningMessageTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-winning-message-text]')

let circleTurn

startGame()

restartButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)

function startGame() {
    circleTurn = false
    cellElements.forEach(cell => {
        cell.classList.remove(X_CLASS)
        cell.classList.remove(CIRCLE_CLASS)
        cell.removeEventListener('click', handleClick)
        cell.addEventListener('click', handleClick, { once: true})
    })
    setBoardHoverClass()
    winningMessageElement.classList.remove('show')
}


function handleClick(e) {
    const cell = e.target
const currentClass = circleTurn ? CIRCLE_CLASS : X_CLASS
placeMark(cell, currentClass)
if(checkWin(currentClass)) {
endGame(false)
} else if (isDraw()) {
    endGame(true)
} else {

//ai takes place in here
Ai()
}
}

function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
  }
///heres the issue
function Ai(cell, CIRCLE_CLASS) {
    if(circleTurn = true)
    {
        let numberGenerator = getRandomInt(9)
        let test = Math.round(cellElements.length * Math.random(9))
        placeMark(test)
    }
}


function endGame(draw) {
    if(draw) {
        winningMessageTextElement.innerText = 'Draw!'
    } else{
        winningMessageTextElement.innerText = `${circleTurn ? "O" : "X"} Wins!`
    }
    winningMessageElement.classList.add('show')

}

function isDraw() {
    return [...cellElements].every(cell => {
        return cell.classList.contains(X_CLASS) ||
        cell.classList.contains(CIRCLE_CLASS)
    })
}

function placeMark(cell, currentClass) {
    cell.classList.add(currentClass)
}

function checkWin(currentClass) {
    return WINNING_COMBINATIONS.some(combination => {
        return combination.every(index => {
            return cellElements[index].classList.contains(currentClass)
        })
    })
}


function setBoardHoverClass() {
    board.classList.remove(X_CLASS)
    board.classList.remove(CIRCLE_CLASS)
    if(circleTurn) {
        board.classList.add(CIRCLE_CLASS)
    }
    else{
        board.classList.add(X_CLASS)
    }
    }
```

Comment: The code `if(circleTurn = true)` actually performs an assignment, - you want `==` (instead of `=`) if you want do do a comparison.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that haha, however I am still having an issue since it's not able to select a random cell.

Comment: Well, the Ai function is a bit funky.. `let numberGenerator = getRandomInt(9)` gets you an int between 0 and 8. Just use it as an index into the NodeList returned by `document.querySelectorAll('div.cell')`. You're calling `placeMark` with `(0 to 8) * 9` when you should be calling it with an element. Make sense now?

Comment: I am unsure where to put this, may you elaborate?

Comment: Inside the conditional test within `Ai`, consider the following statements. `let cells = document.querySelectorAll('div.cell'); let randomIndex = getRandomInt(cells.length); cells[randomIndex].classList.add('CIRCLE_CLASS`);`

Comment: Naturally, this will just set a random cell to contain a circle. Of course, you'll have to check whether this cell is actually available. Also preferable would be some means by which you actually select a cell with the aim of winning, rather than choosing one at random.

Comment: `placeMark` takes two arguments but you only pass one in `ai`. The first argument of `placeMark` must have a `classList` property (i.e. it should be an Element) but you pass a number.